# How to change the key name for each element in array using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of object, which I am showing in table through `ng-repeat`.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in columnHeaders">{{col}}</th> //['Name', 'Bank Name','Code', 'Type','Status'];
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="col in columnRows">{{row[col]}}</td> //['name', 'bankName','code', 'type','isActive'];
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using `ng-repeat` in `<th></th>` and `<td></td>` too. But my `columnHeaders` name and row `property(columnRows)` names are different. I want to change my property name to same as column header name while using `ng-repeat` on `<td></td>` tag.
I am thought of using alias 'as' but not sure how to use it for each element.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: while using ng-repeat for columnRows array I want to change the value of each element same to columnHeaders array. Example:- name ->Name, bankName ->Bank Name and so on.

Comment: The template is used to **display** what the objects contain. Its role is not to modify what the objects contain. The JavaScript code should do that. But I have a hard time understanding why it's desirable to change perfectly valid keys of your ojects, easy to use and respecting naming conventions, into hard to use keys (containing spaces), not respecting naming conventions.

Comment: If you use object keys for string output you are doing it wrong. Keys are internal and if they happen to also be the strings that you want that's a lucky coincidence, If you want to display certain strings for certain keys that's an additional mechanism. What do you do when you change a string (e.g. internationalization), change the code, change all keys??? Don't use keys for string output. Keys are part of the code or the meta data, to show pretty names to users add a translation layer that uses a database of strings, which you can edit independent of the code or the application data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two columnRows and header rows(array of string) , make a single array of keyHash(column data key and header string )

[check running fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/hrghkrjs/)

and code be like :-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="col in columnRows">{{col.displayStr}}</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data track by $index">
          <td ng-repeat="col in columnRows">{{row[col.key]}}</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {


$scope.columnRows = [
 {key:'name',displayStr:'Name'},
  {key:'bankName',displayStr:'Bank Name'},
   {key:'code',displayStr:'Code'},
    {key:'type',displayStr:'Type'},
     {key:'isActive',displayStr:'Status'}
]

  $scope.data = [
   {
   name:'James',
   bankName:'RBL',
   code:'1234',
   type:'Saving',
   isActive:true
   },
   {
   name:'Riyan',
   bankName:'DSB',
   code:'1234',
   type:'Current',
   isActive:true
   }
  ];

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```